# Problemas en el envio de email

Tags: php, html

No me pueden enviar un correo de contacto.

Mi codigo PHP

```
$cuerpo = 'Nuevo contacto: <br /><br />

    <b>Telefono:</b> '.$_POST["telefono"].'<br />
    <b>E-Mail:</b> '.$_POST["mail"].'<br />
    <b>Empresa:</b> '.$_POST["empresa"].'<br />
    <b>Contacto:</b> '.$_POST["contacto"].'<br />
    <b>Direccion:</b> '.$_POST["direccion"].'<br />
    <b>CP:</b> '.$_POST["cp"].'<br />
    <b>Ciudad:</b> '.$_POST["ciudad"].'<br />

    <b>Fax:</b> '.$_POST["fax"].'<br />
    <b>Servicios de Interes:</b> '.$_POST["a"]." ".$_POST["b"]." ".$_POST["c"]." ".$_POST["d"].'<br />
    <b>Mensaje:</b><br />'.nl2br($_POST['msg']);

$to = "abc@abc.com";

if ($_POST["empresa"]=="PRUEBAS") {
    $to = "micorreo@correo.com";
}
$mail= new PHPMailer();
$mail->ContentType = 'text/html';
$mail->CharSet     = 'utf-8';
$mail->From = $_POST['mail'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['empresa'];
$mail->Body = $cuerpo;
$mail->Subject = 'Contacto';
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->Send();
```

Me indica el siguiente error cuando trato de enviar un mensaje, en la consola del log.

[image: Error JS]

y el error, que se indica sale aqui:

```
this.form.getElements("*[class*=validate]").each(function(el) {
    this.register(el);
}, this);
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, con esto.

Ando utilizando `mootools`

http://mootools.floor.ch/js/formcheck/formcheck.js

El error sale de este item

Al momento de ejecutarlo, no lo ejecuta:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        new FormCheck('akira');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: El error que compartes es de JavaScript, deberías compartir información de JavaScript: ¿Es `getElements` un método propio? ¿estás usando alguna librería/framework de JavaScript? ¿qué es `this` y `this.form` en ese contexto? Edita la pregunta para añadir más detalle e información. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve].

Comment: Lo siento, me olvide colocar ello.
Lo añado.